# Index needed for max(col)?

Tags: performance, oracle, statistics, indexing

I'm currently doing some data loading for a kind of warehouse solution. I get an data export from the production each night, which then must be loaded. There are no other updates on the warehouse tables. To only load new items for a certain table I'm currently doing the following steps:

- get the current max value y for a specific column (id for journal tables and time for event tables)
- load the data via a query like `where x > y`

To avoid performance issues (I load around 1 million rows per day) I removed most indices from the tables (there are only needed for production, not in the warehouse). But that way the retrieval of the max value takes some time...so my question is:

What is the best way to get the current max value for a column without an index on that column? I just read about using the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102819/oracle-10g-min-max-column-value-estimation) but I don't know how to handle columns with 'timestamp with timezone'. Disabling the index before load, and recreate it afterwards takes much too long...

Comment: To the close-monger: this is on topic for SO.  It is a question about programming a DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum and maximum values that are computed as part of column-level statistics are estimates.  The optimizer only needs them to be reasonably close, not completely accurate.  I certainly wouldn't trust them as part of a load process.

Loading a million rows per day isn't terribly much.  Do you have an extremely small load window?  I'm a bit hard-pressed to believe that you can't afford the cost of indexing the row(s) you need to do a min/ max index scan.

If you want to avoid indexes, however, you probably want to store the last max value in a separate table that you maintain as part of the load process.  After you load rows 1-1000 in table A, you'd update the row in this summary table for table A to indicate that the last row you've processed is row 1000.  The next time in, you would read the value from the summary table and start at 1001.

Comment: Actually managing this manually in an extra table sound like a good idea... Anyway, regarding the question about creating the index. The table the data gets loaded into has currently about 400 mio rows. Dropping and recreating the index takes a long time...

Comment: @Ingo - I'm not suggesting that you drop & recreate the index every day.  I'm suggesting that creating the index and just leaving it there seems unlikely to cause substantial performance issues if you're only loading a million rows of data every day.

Comment: Unfortunately the load increases from about one minute to nearly an hour...does that sound plausible?

Comment: @Ingo - That does not seem remotely reasonable, no. Do you have a trace of the session that takes an hour?  Or an AWR/ statspack report of the system at the time (assuming there isn't too much else going on)?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not any of that. But as far as I know during loading time there isn't any work at all on the machine. Regarding the trace: What is the best way to get one? Till now I haven't done much dba stuff...sorry. Unfortunately the admins currently don't have time to analyse this for me, so I'm on my own here. In the meantime I think I will stick to your supposed solution. Thanks.

Comment: I just saw another interesting fact. The target table is partitioned on a time column (one partition per month). When I do a a query like 'select * from t where time > sysdate-10' explain plan show that partition pruning takes places. when I do a select max(time) from t I get an partition range -> all.

Comment: @Ingo. The DB doesn't know which (if any) partitions have data. In theory the max(time) could be in any partition so the plan has to accommodate checking every partitions. It doesn't mean it will check every partition on every execution though.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no index on the column, the only way for the DBMS to find the maximum value in the column is a complete table scan, which takes a long time for large tables.

I suppose a DBMS could try to keep track of the minimum and maximum values in the column (storing the values in the system catalog) as it does inserts, updates and deletes - but deletes are why no DBMS I know of tries to keep statistics up to date with per-row operations.  If you delete the maximum value, finding the new maximum requires a table scan if the column is not indexed (and if it is indexed, the index makes it trivial to find the maximum value, so the information does not have to be stored in the system catalog).  This is why they're called 'statistics'; they're an approximation to the values that apply.  But when you request 'SELECT MAX(somecol) FROM sometable', you aren't asking for statistical maximum; you're asking for the actual current maximum.

Comment: Sounds reasonable...to bad due to the fact that I only do inserts... ;-)

Comment: So, would it be better to disable the index before load and update it after a load. If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Have the process that creates the extract file also extract a single row file with the min/max you want.  I assume that piece is scripted on some cron or scheduler, so shouldn't be too much to ask to add min/max calcs to that script ;)

If not, just do a full scan.  Million rows isn't much really, esp in a data warehouse environment.

Answer (score 0):

This code was written with oracle, but should be compatible with most SQL versions:

This gets the key of the max(high_val) in the table according to the range.

```
select high_val, my_key
from (select high_val, my_key
      from mytable
      where something = 'avalue'
      order by high_val desc)
where rownum <= 1
```

What this says is: Sort mytable by high_val descending for values where something = 'avalue'.  Only grab the top row, which will provide you with the max(high_val) in the selected range and the my_key to that table.